# Kotlin map a string to another type?

Tags: kotlin

In swift, I can do

```
"Some String".map { SomeObject($0) }
```

In kotlin it seems like the string is treated as a char array so the result is the map of each character. Is it possible to get similar behavior like the swift code I posted?

```
"Some String".map { SomeObject(it) }
```

Comment: "Is it possible to get similar behavior like the swift code I posted?" You should have mentioned what Swift's behavior is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish something like that with [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html):

```
"Some String".let { SomeObject(it) }
```

If you have an appropriate constructor in place (e.g. `constructor(s : String) : this(...)`) you can also call it as follows:

```
"Some String".let(::SomeObject)
```

[`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) and [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) work also, but are usually taken if you want to rather call a method of the receiver on it. Using `run`/`with` for this would look as follows:

```
"Some String".run { SomeObject(this) }
with ("Some String") { SomeObject(this) }

// but run / with is rather useful for things like the following (where the shown function calls are functions of SomeObject):
val x = someObject.run {
  doSomethingBefore()
  returningSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: I think `let` should be highlighted as the more common one to use in this situation. For one, it matches the way `map` works, in that the lambda you pass to it also takes the value you're transforming as a parameter and it's therefore available as `it`, and I also found it to be used much more commonly in practice.

Comment: You are right... I thought of this also... and mainly the `run` / `with` are rather used, if you call methods of the given receiver in the block. Will restructure the answer

Comment: Thanks... also for the comments :-)

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `let`, `run` or `with`, you can also write an extension method:

```
fun String.toSomeObject() = SomeObject(this)
```

Then use it like follows:

```
"SomeObject".toSomeObject()
```